# String.class.cast(var) vs. Class.forName("java.lang.String").cast(var)

Tags: java

I'm trying to cast an Object variable into, possibly, a variety of other classes. For this example, I'm using String...

```
Object msg = "Hello World";
whatsThis(Class.forName("java.lang.String").cast(msg));
whatsThis(String.class.cast(msg));

protected void whatsThis(String elem)
{
  System.out.println("I'm a String: " + elem);
}

public void whatsThis(Object elem)
{
  System.out.println("I'm an Object: " + elem.toString());
}
```

Output:

> I'm an Object: Hello World
>   I'm a String: Hello World

Why aren't both outputs the String version?

Comment: why it's not Scala ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have here is an overloaded method, `whatsThis`.

For overloaded methods, the method call is bound at compile time. Thus the compiler does not know what object the `cast()` method will return.  It only knows the [declared return type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast(java.lang.Object)) which matches the return type of `Class.forName()` which is java.lang.Object.

```
// Here the compiler knows that the object is a string and can bind the
// method call to the String version of the overloaded method.
whatsThis(String.class.cast(msg));

// Here the compiler knows that Class.forName will return some class object, but
// only at runtime is it known that the class will be the string class.  Thus
// the compiler binds to the Object version of the overloaded method.
whatsThis(Class.forName("java.lang.String").cast(msg));
```